# Strange behavior with transform translateX in CSS3?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>

#parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

#parent:hover #child {
    transform: translateX(50px);
}

#child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The issue is when hovering on the parent, the child moves down a little bit. Why the child moves down while I only specified translateX()?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jMjJvR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is correct, as you are overriding the `transform` parameter.
You have to combine them like

```
#parent:hover #child {
    transform: translateX(50px) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You applied the following style to the #child.

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

So when you are applying new style for the hover situation with

```
transform: translateX(50px);
```

you are basically replacing the original transform with this new one. Thus the -50% displacement in Y axis is reset to 0;

So you have to translate in both X and Y axis again.

```
translate(50px, -50%);
```

This will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when hovering over the `parent` the css for `child` changing and it's overwriting one style. ie., `transform`

in `#child` you have translation on both **x and y** but in hover you are giving only for **x direction**, so the child re-translate to it's old state in **y direction**

you can either do

`transform: translateX(50px) translateY(-50%);`

**OR**

`transform: translate(50px,-50%);`

Here is the working code

```css
#parent {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
}

#parent:hover #child {
 transform: translate(50px,-50%);
}

#child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: aquamarine;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a7dr2sx2/)**